# shower floor drain

Tags: plumbing

I am building a basement shower and using the existing drain. I've opened the floor and found that the 2" drain pipe rises at a slight angle to the floor. Is there such a thing as a flexible ABS connector that I can use to realign the pipe so that it rises straight to make a connection at the floor ? I need to cant it just a few degrees to be square to the floor drain.

Comment: A slight angle change can be made within the glue joints themselves. Depending on the length of pipe to the nearest connection there is a little flex that will give up some of the steep angle too. Don't forget the shower will need a trap under the shower which will afford you a number of joints to do some adjusting if needed.